# How to test an application that implements some cryptographic stuff?

Tags: test-management, test-design

I want to implement the following [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) scheme from [On-the-Fly Multiparty Computation on the Cloud via Multikey Fully Homomorphic Encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/094) by Lopez-Alt et al. I use C++ and I want to know before I start to write the code, how I am going to test my application, what test cases would be useful to imagine for such an application?

I think to feed my application with inputs beyond limits and other tests like this which are considered for every application, but maybe there are some kinds of tests for cryptographic implementations, special things that must be taken account.

For example, if I were to implement a hash function I would test it so that it hasn't significant more collisions than expected by theoretical results. I believe that the same strategy applies in my case.

Comment: Since this is very domain specific question, I think the best place to ask and get a useful answer would be a security community like the information security se